# Selenium sample program: Getting Error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: expected expression, got end of script

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do a sample program with selenium webdriver. I am using libraries from Selenium-java-2.53.1.

Here is my sample program

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ScrollWebPage {

    WebDriver driver;
    String URL="https://www.gmail.com";

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(){
        driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void scrollingToBottom(){
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(URL, "window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");  
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The page is getting opened but it is not able to scroll down. seems an issue with executeScript()

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.executeScript()` expecting `JavaScript` string expression as first arguments while you are providing simply a String as Url which is not an `JavaScript` expression as `exception` says, You need to change :-

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(URL, "window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

to

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

**Note** :- `.executeScript()` expect arguments like `String arg0, Object... arg1` which means first arguments should be `String` but it should be `JavaScript` expression and second arguments should be `Array of Object` like `Object[]`

**In your case no need to provide `URL` as arguments if you simply want to execute scrolling function.**

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Thank you. I removed URL and it worked. Thanks for making me understand what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use as below to see the scroll working. Try in some other page because gmail don't have a much bigger page to feel the scroll.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,2500)");
```